# Get mysql data older than 5 minutes php

Tags: php, mysql

I have search and tried most of the answers and still could not work with my code. I need help with this not sure where is wrong. I insert timeon with `$date = current_time( 'mysql' );`

```
My sql table online

ID  int(11)         
onlineppl   varchar(255)    
timeon  datetime    

data:
ID  onlineppl   timeon
18  1           2014-09-23 12:49:57
17  3           2014-09-23 12:45:00
16  12          2014-09-23 12:44:56

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online WHERE timeon < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


echo $row['onlineppl'];
```

I get no result... need help thanks.

Comment: plz try ur query in mysql and check whether there is any syntax error

Comment: no syntax error, I have checked.

Comment: try with select * without where condition. then check whether its working without where condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM online WHERE timeon < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

Comment: Sorry, no result, is it because of the current_time( 'mysql' ) I insert into timeon? Like time zone different because I have set in wordpress.

Comment: @urber..How you are saving the time? As timestamp(datetime) or unix timestamp (integer)?

Comment: $date = current_time( 'mysql' ); $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO online (onlineppl, timeon) VALUES ( %s, %s )", $onlineid, $date));

Comment: is this %s problem? is timestamp(datetime)

Comment: what is the datatype of `timeon` field?

Comment: timeon field is datetime

Comment: @urber..`current_time( 'mysql' );` returns only time part. So the table entry will be zero.First check whether the field is inserted with correct values.

Comment: ok I understand now, should be the problem with current_time( 'mysql' ) return incorrect values. Thanks, will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @urber..If the field is datetime with correct values, then the query will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

not less then  use greater then

```
 SELECT * FROM online WHERE timeon > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

it's working  use (>=)

Comment: time is greater then(>) sign require